# Display property of object in EJS template

Tags: node.js, json, express, ejs

After using `JSON.stringify` the data I am able to see the output but I only want to print particular data EG `_id`:

```
//Node js 
return res.render('index', {user : req.session.user, robot : doc});

//ejs file
<%=  JSON.stringify(robot) %>
```

I am getting the output as below

```
[{
  "_id": "5c3afbbdfc0c371fe0d643be",
  "category": "robot",
  "name_of_Product": "Bipadle Robot",
  "product_img": "m1.jpg",
  "Front_img": "m1.jpg",
  "side_img": "m1.jpg",
  "price": "1080",
  "discount": "0%",
  "shiping_date": "12/01/2019"
}]
```

but I want to print `_id` only.

I tried using `<%=  JSON.stringify(robot)[0]["_id"] %>` and `<%=  JSON.stringify(robot)[0]._id %>` and even `<%=  JSON.stringify(robot)._id %>`.  I am not able to get the expected output.

Comment: JSON.stringify returns a string, so you should be doing `JSON.parse(robot)[0]._id` instead.

Comment: I tried but it is giving error

Comment: I got the answer by following this way <%- JSON.stringify(robot[0]["_id"]) %> but there is a problem that it is in "5c3afbbdfc0c371fe0d643be" this way. I want to remove the inverted coma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to dereference the `_id` field inside your EJS template:

```
//ejs file
<%= robot[0]['_id'] %>
```

Since the value of `_id` is already a string, you do not need to stringify it.

Comment: I know I am very late to this, but would you mind explaining what you mean by dereference, does that mean the key of the property would not be shown? It would just output the value of the _id ?